# JSX description in Facebook and Typescript docs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, babeljs

Somebody can explain me why the description about JSX
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html
and
https://facebook.github.io/jsx/

describes jsx as JSX "an embeddable XML-like syntax."?,
the xml compiler feature is not only provided by babel react preset and react and not by JSX itself?

https://jsx.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described as XML-like because of the similar **syntax**. Both use Tags <>  for Elements and have a similar structure.

Comment: Of course, but where can i find this syntax here: https://jsx.github.io/

Comment: These are two different JSX, one is developed by Facebook and used in React, the other one is programmed by DeNA Co. a Japanese Company. Beside their name, they are not related to each other

Comment: Thanks, that's it!